# How to make a text in a textbox be clickable in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clickable

I have a textbox. I want to have a text in it, something like, "Click Here" and this text should be clickable.
Once user will click that, I want to display content in the textbox.
So, basically, the link will not be related to url's.
It will be simply, having a text link in textbox, and when user clicks that, it displays some content in textbox and the link then hides.

Note: I do not want to use rich textbox.

Your responses are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use javascript or just put a button to the textbox and when the button is click change the text in the textbox.

Comment: First, is this web forms or MVC? This can be accomplished with javascript or by doing a post back if you are using webforms. Try starting something and when you have a more concise question we can help better. A general "How do I do this?" usually won't get you much help

Comment: Isn't handling jquery click event on the textbox element?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `placeholder` to display "Click here" inside the textbox, not exactly the same as a link but does the job.

You could use javascript to display the content you want when entering the textbox, handling the `onfocus` event.

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()" placeholder="Click Here"/>
```